# How to change an EF connection string, based on subdomain of MVC web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis-7, sql-server-2012

I have an EF5 ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor) web site, running under IIS7.  Now I want to be able to change the connection string to the MSSQL database depending on the subdomain of the URL, e.g. `foo.mydomain.com` should connect to my "Foo" database, and `bar.mydomain.com` should connect to the "Bar" database.

Obviously the DNS records are set up so that they all point to the same web site.

What's the most efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: Why don't you run them as two separate sites with different web configs?  That way you can just set the connection strings in the config file.  It'd be a lot easier and more maintainable than messing around with connection strings each time you declare a context.

Comment: @DoctorJones Because then I have to deploy to that many web sites every time I fix a bug or add a feature.

Comment: @shaul passing in the connection in using dependency injection would be one of the best solutions to the problem. Using a DbContext factory parametrized on site name would be another. If your code does not allow you to do this yet take this as an opportunity to improve it and refactor.

Comment: @LeffeBrune - I don't have a clear picture of what you mean.  Perhaps you could post your suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with what I feel is a better solution than all those proposed to date.  I'm using the default `EntityModelCodeGenerator`, so perhaps there are other, better, solutions for other templates - but this works for me:

1. Create the other half of the partial class `MyEntities`.
2. Override `OnContextCreated()`, which is called from within the class constructor.
3. Change the store connection string using a regex.

This comes out as follows:

```
partial void OnContextCreated()
{
  // change connection string, depending on subdomain
  if (HttpContext.Current == null) return;
  var host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
  var subdomain = host.Split('.')[0];
  switch (subdomain)
  {
    case "foo":
      ChangeDB("Foo");
      break;
    case "bar":
      ChangeDB("Bar");
      break;
  }
}

private void ChangeDB(string dbName)
{
  var ec = Connection as EntityConnection;
  if (ec == null) return;
  var match = Regex.Match(ec.StoreConnection.ConnectionString, @"Initial Catalog\s*=.*?;", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  if (!match.Success) return;
  var newDbString = "initial catalog={0};".Fmt(dbName);
  ec.StoreConnection.ConnectionString = ec.StoreConnection.ConnectionString.Replace(match.Value, newDbString);
}
```

Comment: So you basically did as I said but created your own answer?

Comment: @jgauffin No, I posted this before you posted your comment on your answer.  Your original answer didn't suggest this...

Comment: I did tell you that you can modify the connection string and my example shows that you can use the request (which of course exists in `HttpContext.Current`). I also shown you an alternative way of changing the DB (which also can be done within the context). You just moved it to inside the DbContext, but it's still the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you start passing your own `SqlConnection` to your `YourDbContext`?

```
var partialConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
var connection = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=" + Request.Url.Host + ";" + partialConString);
var context = new MyDbContext(connection, true);
```

You can also change database in the DBContext:

```
context.Database.Connection.ChangeDatabase("newDbname");
```

Comment: I didn't go with this solution because I don't want to have to go back over all my code and change the constructors to pass a connection string everywhere.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: That why IoC containers are so great... Anyway, you could add the database change inside your own DbContext constructor (using `HttpContext.Current`)...

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I did - see my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very easy...
You should change the constructor of object context to dynamically change the connection string.
Take the subdomain name using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`. Then use it to compute the proper connection string.

You should do this in the designer generated code. Of course this is not a good place.. to make it work use the T4 templating. Open your model and right click on the blank designer surface, then select "Add code generation item" -> Ado.net entity object generation. This will create a .tt file. Open it and look for the constructor syntax. Add your logic there.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for mentioning how to get the host off the HttpContext, though I went with my own solution.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Either use different connection strings in the web.config. Maybe research a bit if you can have conditional XSL transformations, that way, when you publish on a specific configuration the web.Release.config will change your Web.Config to be what you need it to be.

Or, use `|DataDirectory|` string substitution - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx

more on DataDirectory string substitution here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1835930.aspx/1?Problem+With+Database+Connection

I guess, if you want to be by the book, create build configurations for each of your separate releases and put the connection string in the respective web..config and when you publish, that XSL transformation will put the connection string in the resulting web.config and voila.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like that recently by adding some custom configuration, which uses the host header to determine the connectionStringName, which has to be used.

EF5 has a constructor, which can handle this name

```
var context = new MyDbContex("name=<DBConnectionStringName>");
```

Comment: I didn't go with this solution, because I don't want to have to go through my entire database replacing all the default constructors with this.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: What do you mean, "use a repository"?  How is that different from what I'm doing now?

Comment: A repository would encapsulate all calls to the database - especially (but not exclusively) instancing of the context. So there's only one location where you would have to change the call of the constructor.

The "quick-but-not-too-dirty" solution would be a mvc base-controller containing the Context for example as (lazy) property.

Answer (score 0):

I just did for a project

```
public partial class admpDBcontext : DbContext
{

    public static string name
    {
        get
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).ToString() == "http://fcoutl.vogmtl.com")
            {
               return "name=admpDBcontext";
            }
            else { return "name=admpNyDBcontext"; }
        }

    }


    public admpDBcontext()
        : base(name)
    {

    }
}
```

And in the web.config I add the connectionString.